# Make large tables in beamer environment

Tags: tables, beamer

I'm trying to make tables in the beamer environment for my presentation.
Unfortunately, longtable does not work at all.
That's my attempt:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{AnnArbor}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=structure,bg=white}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makecell, longtable}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{frame}
I calibrate the model according to the following parameters:    
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline
    $\alpha_n$ & $\alpha_o$ & $\alpha_k$ & $\alpha_s$ & $\mu$ & $\eta$ & $\rho$ & $\nu$  \\ 
    \hline
        0.1 & 0.05 & 0.3 & 0.2 & 0.8 & 1.095 & 0.05 & 0.01\\
        \hline

    \end{tabular}

The model is simulated numerically and gives the following results:

    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline
    $g_D^{\ast}$ & $E^{\ast}$ & $w_n^{\ast}$ & $k_n^{\ast}$ & $\iota_n^{\ast}$ & $\iota_o^{\ast}$ & $\iota_k^{\ast}$ & $\zeta^{\ast}$ & $N_n^{\ast}$
    & $N_o^{\ast}$ &  $N_k^{\ast}$ &
    $N_s^{\ast}$
    \\
    \hline
    0.103& 1.16 & 1.15 & 0.21 & 0.46 & 1.74 & 0.28 & 0.33 & 0.19 & 0.41 & 0.11 & 0.29\\
    \hline
    
\end{tabular}

\end{frame}
```

The first issue is that I should resize the second table since it is too large. The second issue is that I'm not able to write above or below the table, in the sense that words stay attached to the tables.
Also, how can I add a caption (as longtable) in this case?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Thanks so much  :)

Comment: The number of  columns does  not match up.  In the second table, the first row has 13 entries, the second row 12 entries.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean with "that words stay attached to the tables"? After fixing the error with the number of columns, choosing a suitable font size for the table  and adding enough code to make the the code fragments compilable, I get https://i.stack.imgur.com/qACv5.png

Comment: When I say "the words stay attached to the tables", I mean, as shown in your pic, that there is no blank space in the middle of the tables. Btw, how can I change the font size for the table? Is there any way to add a label to it?

Comment: @Mike - While it's ok to immediately upvote answers you find are useful, the site guidelines recommend waiting several hours, or maybe even a full day, before "accepting" any given answer. Why? Because premature acceptances tend to discourage others from posting additonal, possibly even better, answers.

Comment: I'm so sorry about that. I will for the next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- > The first issue is that I should resize the second table since it is too large.

  You choose a suitable font size, e.g. `\tiny` or (better) restructure your table so your audience does not need a magnifying glass
- > Also, how can I add a caption (as longtable) in this case?

  If you use a `table` environment around the table, you can add a caption via the `\caption` macro

Unrelated:

No need to load graphicx, hyperref or amssymb, beamer automatically loads them for you.

The wrapfig package is only of limited use on slides without walls of text. In most cases, columns should be easier to use than a wrapfig.

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{AnnArbor}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=structure,bg=white}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{blindtext}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makecell, longtable}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
I calibrate the model according to the following parameters:    
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline
    $\alpha_n$ & $\alpha_o$ & $\alpha_k$ & $\alpha_s$ & $\mu$ & $\eta$ & $\rho$ & $\nu$  \\ 
    \hline
        0.1 & 0.05 & 0.3 & 0.2 & 0.8 & 1.095 & 0.05 & 0.01\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\caption{some caption for the table}
\label{foo}    
\end{table}

The model is simulated numerically and gives the following results:

\begin{table}
{\tiny
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline
    $g_D^{\ast}$ & $E^{\ast}$ & $w_n^{\ast}$ & $k_n^{\ast}$ & $\iota_n^{\ast}$ & $\iota_o^{\ast}$ & $\iota_k^{\ast}$ & $\zeta^{\ast}$ & $N_n^{\ast}$
    & $N_o^{\ast}$ & $N_o^{\ast}$ & $N_k^{\ast}$
   & $N_s^{\ast}$
    \\
    \hline
    0.103& 1.16 & 1.15 & 0.21 & 0.46 & 1.74 & 0.28 & 0.33 & 0.19 & 0.41 & 0.11 & 0.29 & ???\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}}
\caption{some caption for the table}
\label{bar}
\end{table}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It works, you are a genius. Thanks so much

Comment: @Mike You're welcome!

Comment: Isn't it preferable to reduce the amount of intercolumn whitespace (governed by the parameter `\tabcolsep`) than to impose a 50% linear reduction in font size?

Comment: @Mico I think the preferable approach would be to not show such a big table in a presentation. Such a large numbers of columns is very uncomfortable for the eye to stay in the right columns and the audience will probably not retain a lot of the values. Hence my "or (better) restructure your table so your audience does not need a magnifying glass" remark ...

Comment: I fully agree. Indeed, your comment inspired me to post an addendum to [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/662047/5001) that implements your idea about not creating tables with too many columns in `beamer` documents.

Comment: @Mico Nice solution with the two lines! Too bad one can't upvote an answer twice!

Answer (score 2):

Since `beamer` documents don't have "floating" objects (in the LaTeX-specific sense of the term "float"), I wouldn't use `table` environments. And, since the text that precedes each table pretty much says what each table is about, there's no need for `\caption` statements either.

I would employ a `tabular*` environment for the second table and set its overall width to `\textwidth`. Then, set `\tabcolsep` to 0pt and employ the `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` device to make LaTeX figure out the maximal amount of available intercolumn whitespace.

Observe that by employing a `tabular*` environment, it is *not* necessary to revert to a `\tiny` font size just to make the table fit inside the text block. In fact, the font size doesn't have to be reduced at all.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}} % centered, automatic inline math mode

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
I calibrate the model according to the following parameters:
\[
\begin{array}{@{} *{8}{c} @{}}
%\multicolumn{8}{c}{\mbox{Calibration}} \\[1ex]
\alpha_n & \alpha_o & \alpha_k & \alpha_s & \mu & \eta & \rho & \nu \\
\midrule
0.1 & 0.05 & 0.3 & 0.2 & 0.8 & 1.095 & 0.05 & 0.01 
\end{array}
\]


\bigskip
I simulate the model numerically and obtain the 
following values for the endogenous variables:
\[
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{12}{C} }
%\multicolumn{12}{c}{\mbox{Benchmark simulation}}\\[1ex]
g_D^{\ast} & E^{\ast} & w_n^{\ast} & k_n^{\ast} & \iota_n^{\ast} & \iota_o^{\ast} & 
\iota_k^{\ast} & \zeta^{\ast} & N_n^{\ast} & N_o^{\ast} & N_k^{\ast} & N_s^{\ast} \\
\midrule
0.103 & 1.16 & 1.15 & 0.21 & 0.46 & 1.74 & 0.28 & 0.33 & 0.19 & 0.41 & 0.11 & 0.29 
\end{tabular*}
\]

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*, inspired by a comment by @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz:

- While the answer shown above shows that it is feasible to show the values of all 12 endogenous variables in one row, the spacing is quite tight. Especially for a `beamer` document, it's highly preferable not not to engage in such visual overloading. Instead, just split the 12-column table into two smaller tables, with (say) 7 and 5 columns.
- One rarely goes wrong by providing plentiful visual signposts in a `beamer` document. For instance, one could provide some more explicit visual structure to the page with an `itemize` environment and two `\item` directives.

Implementing these ideas would lead to the following outcome:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for \midrule macro

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}

\item Calibrate the model. 

Choice of values for the 8 parameters:
\[
\begin{array}{@{} *{8}{c} @{}}
\alpha_n & \alpha_o & \alpha_k & \alpha_s & \mu & \eta & \rho & \nu \\
\midrule
0.1 & 0.05 & 0.3 & 0.2 & 0.8 & 1.095 & 0.05 & 0.01 
\end{array}
\]

\item Simulate the model numerically. 

Solution values for the 12~endogenous variables:
\begin{gather*}
\begin{array}{@{} *{7}{c} @{}}
g_D^* & E^* & w_n^* & k_n^* & \iota_n^* & \iota_o^* & \iota_k^* \\
\midrule
0.103 & 1.16 & 1.15 & 0.21 & 0.46 & 1.74 & 0.28 
\end{array}\\[2mm]
\begin{array}{@{} *{5}{c} @{}}
\zeta^* & N_n^* & N_o^* & N_k^* & N_s^* \\
\midrule
0.33 & 0.19 & 0.41 & 0.11 & 0.29 
\end{array}
\end{gather*}

\end{itemize}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```